# Highlight brackets in vim

Tags: vim

I want a special syntax highlight for these 2 patterns:

```
{{
}}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a oneoff:

```
:match Identifier /{{\|}}/
```

For `Identifier` you can pick any highlight group (try `Cursor`, `Error` etc., autcompletion is available when you type `:match`<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

If it's not a one-off, consider writing a syntax highlighting script (`:he mysyntaxfile`)